# Handlers initialized with Looper.getMainLooper() does not respond to message callbacks

Tags: android, multithreading, handler, looper

I am trying to implement Handlers listening on the same Looper from different threads.

Below I have two Handlers, one created in the main thread, another in the child thread, however both are initialized to listen on the Main Looper.

```
private Handler mMain;
public static final ThreadPoolExecutor tpe =
        (ThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mMain = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()) {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            Log.wtf("", "main:" + msg);
        }
    };

    tpe.execute(new Runnable() {
        private Handler tChild = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()) {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                Log.wtf("", "child:" + msg);
            }
        };

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.wtf("", "send msg to main looper");
            tChild.sendEmptyMessage(100);
        }
    });
}
```

But when I send a message like below, only the child handler prints the message. The main handler does not receive the message.

```
03-20 22:02:26.754: A/(12857): send msg to main looper
03-20 22:02:26.847: A/(12857): child:{ what=100 when=-8ms }
```

What am I doing wrong? Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Each `Handler` instance controls the `Message` target and there is no way to get them to share, so every message or post sent to a `Handler` is only executed by that instance.

The `Looper` indicates **which thread** the messages/runnables sent will be executed on.  In your code, both Handlers will execute `handleMessage()` on the main thread, despite being created on separate threads.  That is the real reason you can pass a `Looper` instance to a `Handler`...if you pass no `Looper`, **then** the `Handler` will execute code on the thread in which it was created (which **must** also be a `Looper` thread).

Furthermore, because of this there isn't reason to create multiple Handlers to post data in this manner.  A single `Handler` is designed to be sent messages from multiple threads, and they are all serialized in a `MessageQueue` and executed on the chosen `Looper` thread.  You can post directly to `mMain` from the background thread to execute code on that thread.  In this case, passing the `Looper` is redundant at that code is already on the main thread.

Comment: I see, thanks! Suppose if one day the Runnable was an outer class instead of an inner class, I should pass an initialized Handler to it via its constructor, right?

Comment: The architecture would be application dependent, but you would need a reference to the `Handler` from wherever you plan to post messages to it.

Comment: Why not just use one Handler(this.getMainLooper()) in the Application context (the class that extends Application)?  Wouldn't this be cleaner than doing it in an Activity?

Answer (score 1):

Messages sent to a `Handler` will only be handled by that `Handler`, even if it's sharing a `Looper`.

Buried in the source code for Handler is the line

```
msg.target = this;
```

This ensures no other `Handler` will touch it.